# importing website to google sheets

Tags: import, google-sheets

I have tried searching everywhere online for a good answer but cannot seem to find anything that matches specifically what i am looking for.

When i use the IMPORTHTML function in google sheets, i end up with data that looks like:

```
${player.name} (${player.position}, ${team.abbrev}) ${opponent.abbrev}  #${opponent_rank}   ${minutes}  ${pts}  ${fgm}-${fga}   ${ftm}-${fta}   ${p3m}-${p3a}   ${treb} ${ast}  ${stl}  ${blk}  ${tov}  ${pf}   ${fp}   $${salary}  ${ratio}
```

the code that i am using looks like this:
**=IMPORTHTML("", "table",2)**

When I use the same as above (**=IMPORTHTML("", "table",2)**) only with "0" as my index, it pulls this:

```
Opp     Stats                                                                           
Player  Team    Rank    Min Pts FGM/A   FTM/A   3PM/A   Reb Ast Stl Blk Tov Foul    FP  Cost    Value
```

Basically, I am attempting to pull the table data from this website:

https://www.numberfire.com/nba/fantasy/fantasy-basketball-projections
(because of my rep i cannot post more than two links, however my IMPORTHTML function has the above link input in both functions)
into a google sheet. Please help. any feedback is much appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best advice is to find another Web table you can import. If you do "view source" on the page, you will find that the table content is dynamically populated from a variable named **NF_DATA**.

You need to create a document script to extract the data you want:

```
function this_is_test() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.numberfire.com/nba/fantasy/fantasy-basketball-projections");
  raw_content = response.getContentText();
  re = new RegExp('"daily_projections":\\[[^\\]]+','i');
  proj = raw_content.match(re);
  Logger.log(proj);
}
```

It will extract all text in-between **"daily_projections":[** and **]**, which is (as of today):

```
"daily_projections":[{"nba_player_id":"77","nba_game_id":"20015","date":"2016-01-19","nba_team_id":"21","opponent_id":"7","season":"2016","game_play_probability":"1.00","game_start":"1.00","minutes":36.3,"fgm":"8.8","fga":"17.1","p3m":"1.9","p3a":"4.8","ftm":"6.2","fta":"6.9","oreb":"0.8","dreb":"7.2","ast":"4.7","stl":"1.1","blk":"1.2","tov":"2.7","pf":"1.8","pts":"25.3","ts":"0.628","efg":"0.655","oreb_pct":"2.6","dreb_pct":"21.4","treb_pct":"12.4","ast_pct":"23.4","stl_pct":"1.5","blk_pct":"2.4","tov_pct":"12.1","usg":"27.8","ortg":"122.2","drtg":"101.8","nerd":"22.34","star_street_fp":43.08,"star_street_salary":0,"star_street_ratio":0,"draft_street_daily_fp":39.75,"draft_street_daily_salary":0,"draft_street_daily_ratio":0,"fanduel_fp":43.85,"fanduel_salary":9900,"fanduel_ratio":4.43,"draft_kings_fp":46.55,"draft_kings_salary":9900,"draft_kings_ratio":4.7,"fantasy_feud_fp":39.75,"fantasy_feud_salary":153600,"fantasy_feud_ratio":0.26,"fanthrowdown_fp":45.2,"fanthrowdown_salary":0,"fanthrowdown_ratio":0,"fantasy_aces_fp":44.25,"fantasy_aces_salary":7250,"fantasy_aces_ratio":6.1,"draftday_fp":45.25,"draftday_salary":18800,"draftday_ratio":2.41,"fantasy_score_fp":45.6,"fantasy_score_salary":9600,"fantasy_score_ratio":4.75,"draftster_fp":43.75,"draftster_salary":9400,"draftster_ratio":4.65,"yahoo_fp":44.8,"yahoo_salary":52,"yahoo_ratio":0.86,"treb":8},{"nba_player_id":"397","nba_game_id":"20015","date":"2016-01-19","nba_team_id":"21","opponent_id":"7","season":"2016","game_play_probability":"1.00","game_start":"1.00","minutes":35,"fgm":"8.6","fga":"18.0","p3m":"1.3","p3a":"4.1","ftm":"5.9","fta":"7.2","oreb":"1.3","dreb":"5.0","ast":"8.8","stl":"2.0","blk":"0.4","tov":"3.6","pf":"2.2","pts":"24.4","ts":"0.576","efg":"0.592","oreb_pct":"4.6","dreb_pct":"15.3","treb_pct":"10.2","ast_pct":"44.4","stl_pct":"3.0","blk_pct":"0.8","tov_pct":"14.6","usg":"31.3","ortg":"117.8","drtg":"101.2","nerd":"19.75","star_street_fp":44.48,"star_street_salary":0,"star_street_ratio":0,"draft_street_daily_fp":41.33,"draft_street_daily_salary":0,"draft_street_daily_ratio":0,"fanduel_fp":46.36,"fanduel_salary":10500,"fanduel_ratio":4.42,"draft_kings_fp":49.13,"draft_kings_salary":10700,"draft_kings_ratio":4.59,"fantasy_feud_fp":41.33,"fantasy_feud_salary":169800,"fantasy_feud_ratio":0.24,"fanthrowdown_fp":47.33,"fanthrowdown_salary":0,"fanthrowdown_ratio":0,"fantasy_aces_fp":46.68,"fantasy_aces_salary":7800,"fantasy_aces_ratio":5.98,"draftday_fp":47.1,"draftday_salary":20500,"draftday_ratio":2.3,"fantasy_score_fp":48.48,"fantasy_score_salary":9900,"fantasy_score_ratio":4.9,"draftster_fp":45.38,"draftster_salary":9500,"draftster_ratio":4.78,"yahoo_fp":47.01,"yahoo_salary":59,"yahoo_ratio":0.8,"treb":6.3},{"nba_player_id":"279","nba_game_id":"20016","date":"2016-01-19","nba_team_id":"11","opponent_id":"24","season":"2016","game_play_probability":"1.00","game_start":"1.00","minutes":36.7,"fgm":"7.6","fga":"18.1","p3m":"2.5","p3a":"6.9","ftm":"5.5","fta":"6.5","oreb":"1.1","dreb":"5.8","ast":"5.3","stl":"1.8","blk":"0.4","tov":"3.6","pf":"2.4","pts":"22.5","ts":"0.537","efg":"0.610","oreb_pct":"3.3","dreb_pct":"17.6","treb_pct":"10.5","ast_pct":"25.1","stl_pct":"2.5","blk_pct":"0.9","tov_pct":"15.3","usg":"29.1","ortg":"104.1","drtg":"99.2","nerd":"5.26","star_street_fp":38.55,"star_street_salary":0,"star_street_ratio":0,"draft_street_daily_fp":34.13,"draft_street_daily_salary":0,"draft_street_daily_ratio":0,"fanduel_fp":39.53,"fanduel_salary":8700,"fanduel_ratio":4.54,"draft_kings_fp":42.93,"draft_kings_salary":9200,"draft_kings_ratio":4.67,"fantasy_feud_fp":34.13,"fantasy_feud_salary":138800,"fantasy_feud_ratio":0.25,"fanthrowdown_fp":41.13,"fanthrowdown_salary":0,"fanthrowdown_ratio":0,"fantasy_aces_fp":39.88,"fantasy_aces_salary":6500,"fantasy_aces_ratio":6.14,"draftday_fp":41.3,"draftday_salary":16600,"draftday_ratio":2.49,"fantasy_score_fp":41.68,"fantasy_score_salary":8400,"fantasy_score_ratio":4.96,"draftster_fp":39.45,"draftster_salary":8000,"draftster_ratio":4.93,"yahoo_fp":40.78,"yahoo_salary":47,"yahoo_ratio":0.87,"treb":6.9},{"nba_player_id":"2137","nba_game_id":"20014","date":"2016-01-19","nba_team_id":"38","opponent_id":"17","season":"2016","game_play_probability":"1.00","game_start":"1.00","minutes":35,"fgm":"8.0","fga":"16.6","p3m":"0.4","p3a":"1.3","ftm":"4.5","fta":"6.0","oreb":"2.6","dreb":"7.8","ast":"2.2","stl":"1.0","blk":"2.2","tov":"1.9","pf":"2.6","pts":"20.8","ts":"0.541","efg":"0.521","oreb_pct":"8.6","dreb_pct":"24.8","treb_pct":"16.6","ast_pct":"11.5","stl_pct":"1.4","blk_pct":"4.9","tov_pct":"9.4","usg":"27.0","ortg":"107.9","drtg":"103.1","nerd":"5.60","star_street_fp":41.05,"star_street_salary":0,"star_street_ratio":0,"draft_street_daily_fp":36.55,"draft_street_daily_salary":0,"draft_street_daily_ratio":0,"fanduel_fp":41.08,"fanduel_salary":10300,"fanduel_ratio":3.99,"draft_kings_fp":44.25,"draft_kings_salary":10000,"draft_kings_ratio":4.43,"fantasy_feud_fp":36.55,"fantasy_feud_salary":149400,"fantasy_feud_ratio":0.24,"fanthrowdown_fp":41.8,"fanthrowdown_salary":0,"fanthrowdown_ratio":0,"fantasy_aces_fp":41.6,"fantasy_aces_salary":7400,"fantasy_aces_ratio":5.62,"draftday_fp":40.43,"draftday_salary":18200,"draftday_ratio":2.22,"fantasy_score_fp":42.55,"fantasy_score_salary":9700,"fantasy_score_ratio":4.39,"draftster_fp":41.53,"draftster_salary":9200,"draftster_ratio":4.51,"yahoo_fp":41.28,"yahoo_salary":54,"yahoo_ratio":0.76,"treb":10.4},{"nba_player_id":"362","nba_game_id":"20013","date":"2016-01-19","nba_team_id":"15","opponent_id":"16","season":"2016","game_play_probability":"1.00","game_start":"1.00","minutes":34.9,"fgm":"7.3","fga":"15.4","p3m":"1.4","p3a":"3.7","ftm":"4.8","fta":"6.0","oreb":"1.7","dreb":"6.1","ast":"2.3","stl":"0.7","blk":"1.0","tov":"1.7","pf":"2.0","pts":"20.6","ts":"0.571","efg":"0.594","oreb_pct":"6.2","dreb_pct":"19.9","treb_pct":"13.3","ast_pct":"12.1","stl_pct":"1.1","blk_pct":"2.2","tov_pct":"8.5","usg":"26.5","ortg":"115.3","drtg":"104.5","nerd":"11.63","star_street_fp":34.93,"star_street_salary":0,"star_street_ratio":0,"draft_street_daily_fp":30.85,"draft_street_daily_salary":0,"draft_street_daily_ratio":0,"fanduel_fp":35.11,"fanduel_salary":7800,"fanduel_ratio":4.5,"draft_kings_fp":37.05,"draft_kings_salary":7600,"draft_kings_ratio":4.88,"fantasy_feud_fp":30.85,"fantasy_feud_salary":120400,"fantasy_feud_ratio":0.26,"fanthrowdown_fp":36.2,"fanthrowdown_salary":0,"fanthrowdown_ratio":0,"fantasy_aces_fp":35.5,"fantasy_aces_salary":5900,"fantasy_aces_ratio":6.02,"draftday_fp":35.43,"draftday_salary":13950,"draftday_ratio":2.54,"fantasy_score_fp":36.35,"fantasy_score_salary":7000,"fantasy_score_ratio":5.19,"draftster_fp":35.35,"draftster_salary":7200,"draftster_ratio":4.91,"yahoo_fp":35.81,"yahoo_salary":40,"yahoo_ratio":0.9,"treb":7.8},{"nba_player_id":"2249","nba_game_id":"20014","date":"2016-01-19","nba_team_id":"17","opponent_id":"38","season":"2016","game_play_probability":"1.00","game_start":"1.00","minutes":35.7,"fgm":"7.2","fga":"16.6","p3m":"0.9","p3a":"3.2","ftm":"4.6","fta":"6.3","oreb":"1.3","dreb":"2.9","ast":"2.1","stl":"0.9","blk":"0.5","tov":"2.2","pf":"2.4","pts":"20.2","ts":"0.521","efg":"0.530","oreb_pct":"4.3","dreb_pct":"9.6","treb_pct":"6.9","ast_pct":"10.2","stl_pct":"1.3","blk_pct":"1.0","tov_pct":"10.3","usg":"26.7","ortg":"101.6","drtg":"111.5","nerd":"-7.07","star_street_fp":28.68,"star_street_salary":0,"star_street_ratio":0,"draft_street_daily_fp":23.65,"draft_street_daily_salary":0,"draft_street_daily_ratio":0,"fanduel_fp":28.99,"fanduel_salary":6700,"fanduel_ratio":4.33,"draft_kings_fp":30.75,"draft_kings_salary":6900,"draft_kings_ratio":4.46,"fantasy_feud_fp":23.65,"fantasy_feud_salary":113500,"fantasy_feud_ratio":0.21,"fanthrowdown_fp":29.65,"fanthrowdown_salary":0,"fanthrowdown_ratio":0,"fantasy_aces_fp":29.2,"fantasy_aces_salary":4900,"fantasy_aces_ratio":5.96,"draftday_fp":28.43,"draftday_salary":12000,"draftday_ratio":2.37,"fantasy_score_fp":30.3,"fantasy_score_salary":6000,"fantasy_score_ratio":5.05,"draftster_fp":29.23,"draftster_salary":5900,"draftster_ratio":4.95,"yahoo_fp":29.44,"yahoo_salary":29,"yahoo_ratio":1.02,"treb":4.2},{"nba_player_id":"370","nba_game_id":
```

Note that even this is not complete. You need to somehow map **nba_player_id** to the appropriate name. Anyway, a lot coding will be involved...

Comment: I appreciate the assistance - may take a look into this as it may be worth-while..    Would it be easier though excel?

Comment: Since you can't use `importHTML()`, using Excel (which uses VBA) shouldn't be more difficult than using Google Sheets (which uses Javascript)